# Trustline Created At from Horizon Database

Tags: horizon, ledger

I try to find when is trustline to an asset is created in horizon database. I joining `history_effects`, `history_accounts`, `history_operations` and `history_transactions`. I got `created_at` field on `history_transaction`. But the value is different from it should be, I try to confirm through my Horizon REST API and it gave me different value from my query.

```
created_at  "2018-03-25T10:44:48Z" << from horizon rest api

2018-03-27 03:44:25.553025  << from query
```

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the `history_ledgers` table. The field `closed_at` contains ledger closing timestamp. That filed shows when an operation was actually **applied** to the ledger. Use it instead of `created_at` from `history_transactions`.

And do not forget about timezones. Horizon shows dates in **UTC**, while PostgreSQL converts it to your local timezone.